# Table relationships in EFCore are not included in query

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to run this query:
`var test = (await _db.TableA.Include(c=> c.TableB).Include(c=>c.TableC).ToListAsync();`
The models are as such:

```
[Serializable]
[Table("TableA")]
public class TableA
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TableASpecialIdentifier { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TableB> TableB { get; set; }
    public TableC TableC{ get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[Table("TableB")]
public class TableB
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TableBSpecialIdentifier { get; set; }
    public Guid TableASpecialIdentifier { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TableASpecialIdentifier")]
    public TableA TableA { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[Table("TableC")]
public partial class TableC
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TableCSpecialIdentifier { get; set; }
    public Guid? TableASpecialIdentifier { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TableASpecialIdentifier")]
    public TableA TableA { get; set; }
}
```

When I run it as noted above, nothing comes back. If I run
`var test = (await _db.TableB.Include(c=> c.TableA).ToListAsync();` I get results, same with `var test = (await _db.TableC.Include(c=> c.TableA).ToListAsync();` producing results as well. But trying to include anything into TableC doesnt work.
I have also tried removing the Data Annotations and use the Fluent API like:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<TableB>()
                .HasKey(c => c.TableBSpecialIdentifier);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>()
                .HasKey(f => f.TableASpecialIdentifier);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TableC>()
                .HasKey(c => c.TableCSpecialIdentifier);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TableB>()
                .HasOne(c => c.TableA)
                .WithMany(g => g.TableB)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.TableASpecialIdentifier);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>()
                .HasOne(i => i.TableC)
                .WithOne(c => c.TableA)
                .HasForeignKey<TableC>(f => f.TableASpecialIdentifier);
```

This has the same end result as before. So I tried writing it in LINQ with similar results:

```
var test = (from A in _db.TableA
                        join C in _db.TableC on C.TableASpecialIdentifier equals A.TableASpecialIdentifier
                        join B in _db.TableB on A.TableASpecialIdentifier equals B.TableASpecialIdentifier
                        select C).ToListAsync();
```

I'm not receiving any errors. This is what I'm trying to accomplish written in SQL:

```
Select c.* from TableA a 
   join TableB b on a.TableASpecialIdentifier = b.TableASpecialIdentifier 
   join TableC c on a.TableASpecialIdentifier = c.TableASpecialIdentifier
```

I'm using .net core and EFcore. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
Sorry in advance for the crummy table names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want  to run your query you have to put TableC key as a foreign key  of TableA:

```
public class TableA
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TableASpecialIdentifier { get; set; }

    public Guid TableCSpecialIdentifier { get; set; 

    public ICollection<TableB> TableB { get; set; }
   
   [ForeignKey("TableCSpecialIdentifier")]
    public TableC TableC{ get; set; }
}


public partial class TableC
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TableCSpecialIdentifier { get; set; }
   
     [InverseProperty(nameof(TableA.TableC))]
     public virtual ICollection<TableA> TableAs { get; set; }
}
```

dbcontext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>(entity =>
{
                     entity.HasOne(d => d.TableC)
                    .WithMany(p => p.TableA)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TableCSpecialIdentifier)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
 }
```

Comment: I was able to remove the data annotations and the modelBuilder code. Just needed the InverseProperty annotation and EFCore did the rest. Thank you!